# Kinect for windows v2 not working on my controller pci-usb3 ts-pdu3

Tags: kinect

I have a problem with my kinect for windows v2, when i plug the kinect,

I see white light on the hub and no light on the kinect, is it normal ?

When i launch body basics, I have "kinect not available!"

on my device management i see :

on the WDF KinectSensor Interface 0

it say device can't start (code 10)

I don't know why my device can't start.

I buy a ts-pdu3 because i saw that it's work with kinect on the forum, and i installed the last driver on transcend site : TS-PDU3/PDC3 Driver (uPD720202) (with SATA power connector)

My computer configuration is :

Motherboard : P5KPL-VM

Processor : Intel Core2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz

Graphic card : NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GT]

PCI to USB3 controller : TS-PDU3

Comment: I think that my pcix port are not gen 2 and not support 5.0GB/s transfer so it can't work on my motherboard.

Comment: download the latest SDK (August 20), it has a new Kinect Configuration verifier tool that will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: the problem was my graphic card, i just bought a new graphic card and it works. Thanks.